# Scala: build Map with pattern matching

Tags: scala

I am trying to build a `Map[String, Any]` like this:

```
Map(
  somevalues match {
   Some(v) => ("myvalues -> v)
   None => ???
},

  othervalues match {
   Some(v) => ("othervalues -> v)
   None => ???
},
...etc
)
```

which value should I use for the none case as I don't want to insert anything in the map in that case?

Comment: What are the types in your map? And what types are `somevalues` and `othervalues`?

Comment: Why is your value type `Any`? You can't be any more specific?

Comment: Int, String, Double, pretty much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

```
List(
  someValues match {
    case Some(v) => Some("myValues" -> v)
    case None => None
  },

  otherValues  match {
    case Some(v) => Some("otherValues" -> v)
    case None => None
  },
  ...
).flatten.toMap
```

or shortened:

```
List(
  someValues.map("myValues" -> _),

  otherValues.map("otherValues" -> _),
  ...
).flatten.toMap
```